# RESTful urls in ColdFusion 11

Tags: coldfusion, cfwheels, coldfusion-11

I just moved my CFWheels app from CF9 to CF11 and I've lost the REST urls from my previous setup.

For example before I had `example.com/controller/view` and now I get `example.com/index.cfm?controller=foo&action=bar`

The weird thing is that when I hardcode the url in it doesn't convert it or throw an error.

Is there a setting in the administrator's panel that I should check? I did a comparison with my previous setup but I have't found anything.

Comment: I think you will need to investigate a rewrite technology for this - something (perhaps) wheels does internally - no?

Comment: there is a file called web.config for IIS where you can enable url rewriting but still doesn't work even though when you are at the login of the site you get example.com/register/login and then it's switching back to the traditional url

Comment: Did you review the info in the [URL Rewriting](http://cfwheels.org/docs/chapter/url-rewriting) chapter? Also, try `set(urlRewriting="full")` in `config/settings.cfm`.

Comment: @ChrisPeters I just got ti work. but I will check your recommendation as well..

Comment: Be sure to post your solution as an answer.

Comment: yes.. how exactly did you get it to work :)

Comment: @ChrisPeters can you add your comment as an answer please so I can accept it

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did to get it to work.

I uncomented the xml code inside web.config in the root of my application. Set the `<directoryBrowse enabled="true" />` renamed the `htaccess` and `ISAPIrewrite4.ini`. Then `restarted the server and Coldfusion` through services.

I think the trick happened when I renamed the two files that were unnecessary for my setup (htaccess for apache and ISAPI rewrite for IIS 6).

Good luck to anyone running through this issue :)